# Incorrect Inbox notification Email

Tags: bug, global-inbox, email

Just got an email from Stack Exchange:

[image: Email screenshot]

However, I'm on Stack Exchange (almost) every day. Is this a bug that it informs me that I haven't looked at my inbox since May?

Comment: Do you have any other accounts?

Comment: No. Also, the email items related to this account.

Comment: +1 I also sometimes get weird notifications about chat message pings that I've seen an hour before the notification.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani Not related in any way....

Comment: @Nic I know, just indicating that bugs can be interesting sometimes. :)

Comment: I had this happen to me as well, except for 2015-05-27. I have been on SE a lot in that time and would reckon I was last on on 2015-07-17 when I received this email on 2015-07-19. I assume that commenting here is the appropriate way to register my getting this rather than opening a duplicate question?